# asp.net/VB.net: OnClientClick function shows up after postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, onclientclick

I want to show a confirm dialog in my asp.net/VB.net application.

I'm adding programmatically the OnClientClick method in the `Click` event of a buton.

My code:

```
Protected Sub btn_send_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_send.Click
        btn_send.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Proceed?');"
End Sub
```

The dialog is displayed **after the first postback** of the site.

After I've made a postback, the dialog shows up on every click. But when I'm callin the page without a postback, no dialog shows up and the page does its postback.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the `OnClientClick` property *before* the button gets clicked, not after it.

So in your `Page_Load` or `Page_Init` methods, put the code you had in your button's click handler:

```
btn_send.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Proceed?');"
```